# Gmail/google notification security level low security apps like emphaty/evolution?

Tags: security, google, gmail

Very often I receive notifications for Google to access non-secure applications with lower standards to the levels specified google when maybe emphaty or evolution access to accounts / mail gmail, as sometimes happens when my computer is synchronized automatically, there is an update of these applications in terms of security protocols that avoid sending mail notification from google?
Keep in mind gmail 2 step verification (smarhphone ...) and others google security level ...
Thank you so much for updates ...;)

Comment: What do the notifications say?

Comment: Access gmail account from someone .... unless you're sure to be you ... change password ... google can not know if the same devices (Linux), you can disable notification by clicking on active applications with lower standards of safety in the settings .

Comment: Because these applications unlike the system does not update more often?
Or rather use only login via web-desktop?
With the smartphone it does not happen even if they are not sure 100% too ...
Many thanks for the answers ... difficult;)
I do not think a hacker ..

Comment: Exscuse me, message refer to evolution and empathy update, use or not...

Comment: It's better use webmail-gmail desktop login and not this application?

Comment: It could be when you synchronize empathy like google drive or something?
The accounts are accessed only via gmail and altomail 2step verification ...

Comment: See that `Edit` button below your question?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about those clients in particular but thunderbird has been updated to support Google's regular Oauth login which works with 2FA as well.

If you would like to continue using those clients its possible to change a setting on your google account to allow regular email login but I doubt you could do this with 2FA.

I recommend you install thunderbird from the ubuntu repos to use with gmail.